# student multi add user script, broken filter on get-aduser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

hi just student trying to Bulk add Users from a .csv
when using this, its breaking at the User Filter, but I'm unsure why
error says this line is the issue
" if (Get-ADUser -F { sAMAccountName -eq $username })
Get-ADUser: The search filter cannot be recognized"
i think the csv import is fine but I'm new to this so not really sure what causing the filter to break

```
$ADUsers = Import-csv 'Path'
#$apiRequest = Get-Content -Raw -Path path.json | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {


        $firstName = $user.FirstName
        $surname = $user.Surname
        $branch = $user.Branch
        $city = $user.City
        $country = $user.Country
        $company = $user.CompanyName
        $countryCode = $user.CountryCode
        $email = $user.Email
        $userType = $User.UserType
        $vaildUsernameFormat = "[^a-zA-Z_]"                                                  # anything that's _not_ a-z or underscore
        $username = ($firstName.$surname) -replace $vaildUsernameFormat, ''       #removes anything that isn't a-z
        $ou = $User.ou


        #Check if the user account already exists in AD
        if (Get-ADUser -F { sAMAccountName -eq $username }) {
                #If user does exist, output a warning message
                Write-Warning "A user account $username has already exist in Active Directory."

        }
        else {
                #If a user does not exist then create a new user account

                New-ADUser `

                -co  $country
                -company $company
                -countryCode $countryCode
                -department $department
                -displayName $username
                -sn $surname
                -st $streetName
                -title $title

        }
}
```

thanks for anything you can offer

full error message is

```
Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At "path" csv.ps1:41 char:13
+         if (Get-ADUser -F { sAMAccountName -eq $username }) {
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: what is the FULL error msg text? PoSh usually has useful info in that text. _please_, add it to your Question & wrap it in code formatting so that it will be easy to read. [*grin*]

Comment: error code added.

Comment: thanks! [*grin*] ///// [1] have you confirmed that `$UserName` has something in it at that point? [2] have you confirmed that it has what your expect? [3] have you confirmed that it is valid? [4] does `Get-ADUser -F { sAMAccountName -eq $username }` work when used all on its own [with a valid value in the $Var]? [5] have you tried using a STRING [as the docs state is required] instead of a scriptblock?

Comment: Add a `Write-Host $username` just before your if statement so you can validate what is actually in the variable just prior to it being used.

Comment: `$username = ($firstName.$surname) -replace $vaildUsernameFormat, ''` is wrong and returns nothing. Combine the username like this `$samaccountname = '{0}.{1}' -f $firstName, $surname`. Then of course... If you replace all characters not in `"[^a-zA-Z_]"`, the dot you have added gets removed again.

Comment: Also, have a look at [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) the parameters to the `New-ADUser` cmdlet. This makes clean code and you don't have to worry about the nasty backticks, which BTW you forgot.. Do some more searching, There are **LOTS** of examples on SO how to create new users via a CSV file.