# Student Script for creating new users error :System.String' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm pulling some user info from a .csv to create new users, 
I've splatted the New User Params at the suggestion of someone here

but I'm getting this error

```
New-ADUser : Cannot convert 'System.String' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter' required by parameter 
'Confirm'.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\cyclone-internal-user-sync-1\Bamboo Attributes form a csv.ps1:68 char:28
+                 New-ADUser @NewUserParms
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

I have no idea what this is haha, I've tried adding an erroraction stop to the new-aduser but that didn't have any effect

I have added trims and a section to remove spaces from usernames. to deal with multipart names such as Van der.... etc

```
#Bamboo Attributes from a .csv

#Enter a path to your import CSV file
$ADUsers = Import-csv 'path'


#Bamboo Attributes from a .csv

#Enter a path to your import CSV file
$ADUsers = Import-csv 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\GitHub\cyclone-internal-user-sync-1\documentation\SampleUserAttributes.csv'
#$apiRequest = Get-Content -Raw -Path C:\Users\alexh\Documents\GitHub\cyclone-internal-user-sync-1\cyclone-internal-user-sync-1\fake-api-query.json | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {


        $firstName = $user.FirstName.Trim()
        $surname = $user.Surname.Trim()

        $vaildUsernameFormat = "[^a-zA-Z_.]"                                        # identifies anything that's _not_ a-z or underscore or .
        $username = "($firstName'.'$surname)" -replace $vaildUsernameFormat, ''       #removes anything that isn't a-z

        $DefaultPassword = 'Pa$$w0rd'

        $NewUserParms = @{
                'samAccountName'         = $username;
                'Name'                   = "$firstname $surname";
                'DisplayName'            = "$firstname $surname";
                'UserPrincipalName'      = "$username@domain.com";
                'GivenName'              = $firstname;
                'Surname'                = $surname;
                'EmailAddress'           = $User.Email;
                'AccountPassword'        = (ConvertTo-SecureString $DefaultPassword -AsPlainText -Force);
                'Enabled'                = $true;
                'Path'                   = "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com";
                'co'                     = $User.Country;
                'company'                = $User.CompanyName;
                'countryCode'            = $user.countryCode;
                'department'             = $user.OrgDepartmentName;
                'Employeeid'             = $user.EmployeeId;
                'exstentionAttribute1'   = $user.ExstentionNumber;
                'ipPhone'                = $user.ExstentionNumber;
                'L'                      = $user.location;
                'mail'                   = $user.Email;
                'mobile'                 = $user.Mobile;
                'Manager'                = $user.Manager;
                'physicalDeliveryOffice' = $user.Branch;
                'postalCode'             = $user.PostalCode;
                'postOfficeBox'          = $user.PostOfficeBox;
                'proxyAddresses'         = $user.ProxyEmail;
                'scriptPath'             = $user.scriptPath;
                'st'                     = $user.StreetName;
                'Title'                  = $user.Title

        }




        write-host "$username this is username value"



        #Check if the user account already exists in AD
        if (Get-ADUser -F {
                        sAMAccountName -eq $username
                }) {
                #If user does exist, output a warning message
                Write-Warning "A user account $username has already exist in Active Directory."

        }
        else {
                #If a user does not exist then create a new user account

                New-ADUser @NewUserParms


        }
}
```

I've removed some of the user attributes just to make this a bit smaller.
here is the.csv as well in case I've messed something up there
[link to .csv file on git](https://github.com/alexhuntinbox/Test1/blob/master/SampleUserAttributes.csv)

Comment: [1] why did you remove the previous post? it pointed out your error with `$` instead of `@` in your splat call. [2] to get proper use out of the `Stop` error action, one normally wraps the call in a `try/catch` structure.

Comment: I remember commenting of the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61739851/student-multi-add-user-script-broken-filter-on-get-aduser) about the same thing and there I gave you the link to read about [Splatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting). As @Lee_Dailey says, use `New-ADUser @NewUserParms`. Also, instead of `Get-ADUser -F {sAMAccountName -eq $username}` write `Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'"`. BTW the error you show is about the `Confirm` switch, which you don't use in the code..

Comment: sorry, i just realized that i grabbed the un-updated code from my previous post, i hadn't pushed the change to my repo.
the error that i have about the confirm, was happening before i added the confirm parameter, i simpler tried added that so see if it would resolve the issue, and then removed the parameter when it did not. the error is still the same, i have updated the code. it still gives the same error with the confirm parameter removed, 
but fro clarity i have updated the error message as well.

Comment: i havn't removed the other post, i was under the impression that if i have a spereate issues i am supposed to create a new post, unfortunately me not pushing my updated code to my repos seems to have made some confusion here. i am aware of the splatting error and fixed that and made this post as it was a new problem. 
apologies, for any misleading information, I'm new to this. but thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little known fact about PowerShell is that you don't need to use the whole parameter name. You can use the partial name and as long as it matches only one parameter name, that's what PowerShell assumes you mean.

The one it's choking on is this:

```
            'co'                     = $User.Country;
```

If you look at [the documentation for `New-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-aduser), it does not have a parameter called `co`. So PowerShell assumes it's a partial match to a known parameter, and the closest match is `-Confirm`. And the value in `$User.Country` doesn't make any sense for the `-Confirm` parameter, so it throws the error.

You will have to use the `-OtherAttributes` parameter to set all the other attributes that `New-ADUser` doesn't have a dedicated parameter for:

```
$NewUserParms = @{
    ...

    'OtherAttributes = @ {
        'co' = $User.Country;
        'exstentionAttribute1' = $user.ExstentionNumber;
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: the error message was showing before i added the confirm, i didn't run the script again after removing the confirm parameter as the error was the same, my apologies for any confusion caused. i was trying to explain what i  had already tried

Comment: I see. Now that I see your updated code, I see the issue. I've updated my answer.

Comment: ah thanks, i was using a list of attributes given to me by a friend so i just assumed they were correct, thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

As commented in this and previous questions, you are using `New-ADUser $NewUserParms`, where it should be `New-ADUser @NewUserParms`.

Also, to catch errors (you **did** add `-ErrorAction Stop`), you need to put that inside a `try{..} catch{..}` block.

I would also change the syntax you use for the `-Filter` parameter. Instead of using a scriptblock syntax `{something -eq someotherthing}`, you should create a string like `"something -eq 'someotherthing'"`

Try:

```
# define some 'constants'
$csvFile           = 'X:\Folder\NewUsers.csv'  # Enter a path to your import CSV file
$invalidCharacters = '[^a-z_.]'                # identifies anything that's _not_ a-z or underscore or .
$DefaultPassword   = 'Pa$$w0rd'
$securePassword    = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $DefaultPassword -AsPlainText -Force

# read the input csv and loop through
Import-Csv -Path $csvFile | ForEach-Object {
    $firstName = $_.FirstName.Trim()
    $surname   = $_.Surname.Trim()
    $username  = ('{0}.{1}' -f $firstName, $surname) -replace $invalidCharacters

    # test if a user with that name already exists
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        Write-Warning "A user account $username already exist in Active Directory."
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Creating user $username"

        $NewUserParms = @{
            'SamAccountName'    = $username
            'Name'              = "$firstname $surname"
            'DisplayName'       = "$firstname $surname"
            'UserPrincipalName' = "$username@domain.com"
            'GivenName'         = $firstname
            'Surname'           = $surname
            'EmailAddress'      = $_.Email
            'AccountPassword'   = $securePassword
            'Enabled'           = $true
            'Path'              = "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
            # add other properties to set from the CSV here.
            # make sure you get the parameter data types correct and always check here:
            # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-aduser?view=win10-ps#parameters
            # switch parameters for the cmdlet can also be entered with a value $false or $true
        }

        try {
            # '-ErrorAction Stop' ensures that also non-terminating errors get handled in the catch block
            New-ADUser @NewUserParms -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch {
            # something bad happened. Change 'Write-Warning' into 'throw' if you want your script to exit here
            # inside a catch block, the '$_' automatic variable represents the actual exception object.
            Write-Warning "Could not create account $username. $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed respose theo, will run this and get back.

Comment: hi Theo, thanks for this, it works, except that i needed to change the "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com" line to "CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
otherwise, i no longer have the previous error.
although if anyone does know the cause i would still like to know. as while having a working script is nice, i kinda want to know what my mistake in my own was. the journey is about what you see on the way not the destination or something wise like that i guess

Comment: @alexhunt The `Path` needs the full distinguishedName of the OU you want to create the users in. Best to always open ADUC, right-click the OU and copy the `distinguishedName` value from its properties. As for the `-Confirm` switch, there is no such switch on `New-ADUser`. Finally, there was a small mistake in using `$NewUserParms` instead of `@NewUserParms`. I think that sums it all up. Your code was really close and only failed on these minor mishaps.

Comment: @alexhunt P.S. You can also copy the `distinguishedName` property for the OU by running `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*"' | Format-Table Name, DistinguishedName`

Comment: thanks fo the help earlier, but running does not populate the other csv values when i pull them from the csv ie: $user.Country, in the script you provided you supplied $_.email, which works fine because the value is just firstname.lastname. but as the script no longer has a for each user in users i can't use $user.country or $user.PostOfficeBox etc, how would I fill these out

Comment: @alexhunt The script now uses `ForEach-Object`, so simply add new properties from the csv using the `$_` automatic variable, just like with `'EmailAddress'  = $_.Email`, simply add the other properties: `'Country' = $_.Country` and `'POBox' = $_.PostOfficeBox`. Check [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-aduser) what the exact property names for the New-ADUser cmdlet are.

Comment: hmm, I've tried that and I get a message saying that the A value for the attribute was not in the acceptable range of values when I try 'country' = $_.Country. i have already checked that the value for $_.Country is a string 'France'

Should i just open a new Question with this ?

Comment: Nevermind, im an idiot haha i assumes when it asked for a string it was the full name of the country, when its supposed to be the country code.